# How to animate the deletion of an item in list using SwipeAction? Realm, Swiftui

Tags: swiftui, realm

I'm trying to animate the deletion of an item when swiping left in a list but it's not working. I'm using Realm to save the tasks. The deletion is applied immediately without animation even though the action is wrapped inside withAnimation.

I noticed that when i use the onDelete modifier the animation is playing well but there is no animation with swipeAction

```swift
import SwiftUI
import RealmSwift

struct TasksView: View {
    
    @StateObject var tasksViewModel: TasksViewModel = TasksViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        List {
            if let tasks = tasksViewModel.tasks {
                ForEach(tasks.freeze(), id: \.id) { task in
                    Text(task.title)
                        .swipeActions(edge: .trailing, allowsFullSwipe: true) {
                            Button(role: .destructive) {
                                withAnimation {
                                    if let taskToDelete = task.thaw() {
                                        tasksViewModel.archive(taskToDelete)
                                    }
                                }
                            } label: {
                                Image("delete")
                            }
                            .tint(.red)
                        }
                }
            }
        }

    }
}

struct TasksViewNew_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TasksView()
    }
}
```

```swift
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

@MainActor
class TasksViewModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published var tasks: List<Task>?
    
    var token: NotificationToken?

    init() {
        let realm = try! Realm()
        let group = Group()
        do {
            try realm.write {
                let tasks = [Task(title: "TaskA"),
                             Task(title: "TaskB"),
                             Task(title: "TaskC"),
                             Task(title: "TaskD"),]
                realm.add(group)
                group.tasks.append(objectsIn: tasks)
                self.tasks = group.tasks
            }
        } catch {
            print("error")
        }
        
        token = group.observe({ (changes) in
              switch changes {
              case .error(_):
                  break
              case .change(_, _):
                  self.objectWillChange.send()
                  break
              case .deleted:
                  break
              }
              
          })
        
    }
    
    func archive(_ task: Task) {
        do {

            let realm = try Realm()
            try realm.write {
                realm.delete(task)
            }

        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    
}
```

```swift
class Task: Object {
    @Persisted var id: String = UUID().uuidString
    @Persisted var title: String

    convenience init(title: String) {
        self.init()
        self.title = title
    }
}

class Group: Object, ObjectKeyIdentifiable {
    @Persisted var _id = ObjectId.generate()
    @Persisted var tasks = List<Task>()
}
```

Comment: A couple of suggestions; you could probably simplify your code by using `@ObservedRealmObject` property wrapper on your List. That automatically opens a write transaction as needed. Also, it's not clear why these objects are frozen. Also maybe adding `.onDelete(perform:` to the List items would simplify the code as well.

Comment: Any luck / progress? It appears that I am encountering the same issue, with a simple `Array` of `String`s as my model. So I doubt the animation issue has something to do with Realm(?).

Answer (score 3):

As a followup to my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69336564/how-to-animate-the-deletion-of-an-item-in-list-using-swipeaction-realm-swiftui#comment123584292_69336564) on the original question, I here post my code where I encounter a similar issue with animating a deletion triggered using `.swipeAction()`. For better comparison, my View allows to switch between the custom deletion and a deletion using `.onDelete()`. The result shows the difference as such:

[image]

The code is based on Paul Hudson's [example](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-let-users-delete-rows-from-a-list), but he only prints out a deletion message to showcase that the button is tapped.

```
// Friends.swift

import Foundation

class Friends: ObservableObject {
    @Published var list = ["Antoine", "Bas", "Curt", "Dave", "Erica"]
    
    func remove(friend: String) {
        if let index = list.firstIndex(of: friend) {
            list.remove(at: index)
        }
    }
    
    func remove(at indexSet: IndexSet) {
        list.remove(atOffsets: indexSet)
    }
}
```

```
// ContentView.swift

import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var friends: Friends
    
    @State private var usingOnDelete = false
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section {
                Toggle("Using onDelete", isOn: $usingOnDelete)
            }
            
            Section {
                if usingOnDelete {
                    listUsingOnDelete
                } else {
                    listNotUsingOnDelete
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Deletion test")
    }
    
    private var listUsingOnDelete: some View {
        ForEach(friends.list, id: \.self) { friend in
            Text(friend)
        }
        .onDelete { friends.remove(at: $0) }
    }
    
    private var listNotUsingOnDelete: some View {
        ForEach(friends.list, id: \.self) { friend in
            Text(friend)
            .swipeActions(allowsFullSwipe: true) {
                Button(role: .destructive) {
                    withAnimation {
                        friends.remove(friend: friend)
                    }
                } label: {
                    Label("Delete", systemImage: "trash.fill")
                }
                
                Button {
                    print("Muting conversation")
                } label: {
                    Label("Mute", systemImage: "bell.slash.fill")
                }
                .tint(.indigo)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ContentView()
        }
        .environmentObject(Friends())
    }
}
```

```
// MainApp.swift

import SwiftUI

@main
struct MainApp: App {
    @StateObject var friends = Friends()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationView {
                ContentView()
            }
            .environmentObject(friends)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a solution to this problem? Or are we waiting for an update... :)

Comment: I haven't found a solution as of yet, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug in SwiftUI's List.
Adding plain style to the list fixes this, but in my opinion it doesn't look as good.

```swift
.listStyle(.plain)
```

I've submitted feedback for this issue, as it can be reproduced with vanilla SwiftUI.